# React issue when tryign to play mp3

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following: (with some sample mp3, npm package used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sound)

```
import React from 'react';
import Sound from 'react-sound';

class CustomSound extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Sound
              url="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"
              playStatus={Sound.status.PLAYING}
              playFromPosition={0 /* in milliseconds */}
              onLoading={this.handleSongLoading}
              onPlaying={this.handleSongPlaying}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default CustomSound;
```

which I am importing here:

```
...

import CustomSound from './js/customSound.jsx';

...

        if(currentState.visibility.grid) {
            grid =  <Grid 
                        visibility={currentState.visibility.grid}
                        visibilityCustomCity={currentState.visibility.city}
                        setVisibility={this.setVisibility}
                        current={currentState.data}
                        points={currentState.points}
                        addPoints={this.addPoints}
                        setVisibility={this.setVisibility}
                        setCatBgColor={this.setCatBgColor}
                        catBgColor={currentState.catBgColor}
                        bgImg={currentState.bgImg}
                        setFinalPlay={this.setFinalPlay}
                        setBgColor={this.setBgColor}
                        setCountVisibility={this.setCountVisibility}
                    >
                        <CustomSound />
                    </Grid>
        }

        if(currentState.visibility.timeUp) {
            timeUp =    <TimeUp 
                            visibility={currentState.visibility.timeUp}
                            setVisibility={this.setVisibility}
                            setCountVisibility={this.setCountVisibility}
                        />
        }

        if(currentState.finalPlay.correct) {
            correct =   <Correct setBgColor={this.setBgColor} setHeaderVisible={this.setHeaderVisible} points={currentState.points} setFinalPlay={this.setFinalPlay} setVisibility={this.setVisibility} />
        }

        if(currentState.finalPlay.incorrect) {
            incorrect = <Incorrect setBgColor={this.setBgColor} resetPoints={this.resetPoints} setHeaderVisible={this.setHeaderVisible} points={currentState.points} setFinalPlay={this.setFinalPlay} setVisibility={this.setVisibility} />
        }

        return (
            <div className={"wrapper " + currentState.bgColor}>
                <div className="wrapper-inner">
                    <h1 className={isH1Visible}><span>the big</span> reveal</h1>
                    {form}
                    {cat}
                    {grid}
                    {timeUp}
                    {correct}
                    {incorrect}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

However, when "currentState.visibility.grid" is set to true the sound doesn't play.

No errors in the console apart from this:

```
SoundManager V2.97a.20170601 (HTML5-only mode)
soundmanager2.js?afc8:1305 SoundManager 2 HTML5 support: mp3 = true, mp4 = true, ogg = true, opus = true, wav = true, flac = true
soundmanager2.js?afc8:1305 SoundManager 2: Ready. ✓
```

**UPDATE**

if  is moved to:

```
return (
    <div className={"wrapper " + currentState.bgColor}>
        <div className="wrapper-inner">
        <CustomSound />
            <h1 className={isH1Visible}><span>the big</span> reveal</h1>
            {form}
            {cat}
            {grid}
            {timeUp}
            {correct}
            {incorrect}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

the sound plays.

Comment: any errors on console?

Comment: @bennygenel see updated answer. Thank you.

Comment: Is your `Grid` component loading?

Comment: have you added `handleSongLoading` and `handleSongPlaying` to CustomSound component?

Comment: @bennygenel the grid is loading correctly..

Comment: I didn't ask the Grid. I asked the CustomSound component.

Comment: @bennygenel well, there is no visual to say it's loading. The proof would be the sound playing.

Comment: I was trying to learn if you added any functions to `handleSongLoading` and `handleSongPlaying`. You can add console.log to see if the functions firing so if the problem is just sound not playing or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add it as a child of the `Grid`. Instead, pass it in as a sibling:

```
if(currentState.visibility.grid) {
    grid =  <div>
        <Grid
            visibility={currentState.visibility.grid}
            visibilityCustomCity={currentState.visibility.city}
            setVisibility={this.setVisibility}
            current={currentState.data}
            points={currentState.points}
            addPoints={this.addPoints}
            setVisibility={this.setVisibility}
            setCatBgColor={this.setCatBgColor}
            catBgColor={currentState.catBgColor}
            bgImg={currentState.bgImg}
            setFinalPlay={this.setFinalPlay}
            setBgColor={this.setBgColor}
            setCountVisibility={this.setCountVisibility}
        />
        <CustomSound />
    </div>;
}
```

Note the surrounding div. So now you'll be returning a div with `Grid` and `CustomSound` in it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does that affect the sound not being played?

Comment: Not sure where you're getting your `Grid` component from, but you were passing the mp3 in as a child, so the `Grid` component would have to add `this.props.children` to it's render method, which looks like it wasn't, so the mp3 was never getting rendered. When you move it out, it will always get rendered with the `Grid`.

Comment: I am guess I am still a newbies to React (this.props.children). Thank you!